# Changing org colour order with solarized theme

Tags: org-mode, colors

Using the solarized theme from
[this repository](http://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs), how can I change the
colour order of org headings?  I like the default order better
than those defined in the solarized package, but would like the colours
in low contrast versions.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/blob/master/solarized.el), it appears that the colors are hard-coded.  I believe that the faces you want are `org-level-1` through `org-level-8` starting at line 1621.

Comment: @Dan, thanks, I'll just change the source then.